# remove hidden class on X items per click on list

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

I have a large list of transactions where only 5 items are visible at page load.

I have a button to load the rest by simply removing a "hidden" class. But I do not want to display them all at the button click but only 5 at a time.

I am a bit unsure of how I can do this.

My current script

```
const cashBackTransactionsWrapper = document.querySelector('.cashback--transactions');

  if (cashBackTransactionsWrapper !== null) {
    const morePostingsButton = document.querySelector('.cash-back--morepostings');

    morePostingsButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      const cashbackTableRowHidden = cashBackTransactionsWrapper.querySelectorAll('.flex-table.hidden');

      for (var i = 0; cashbackTableRowHidden.length > 0; i++) {
        cashbackTableRowHidden[i].classList.remove('hidden');        
      }
    });
  }
```

What I want to achieve is that when the user click the "morepostings" button the next 5 items have their hidden class remove. When the user clicks the button again, the next 5 items have the class removed and so forth.

A pagination-style functionality, if you will.

Comment: do you have an HTML snippet so we can test it on a fiddle?

Comment: You have infinite for loop. Replace your condition with i < 5. Should help :>

Comment: @ManuilovVyacheslav - MAN! The solution is often so simple it's hard to see! Thank you! Will you place an answer?

Comment: @MortenHagh Fresh look often helps to find the problem. Your eyes was just blurred :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have infinite for loop. You should replace your condition with i < 5. Should help :)

```
const cashBackTransactionsWrapper = document.querySelector('.cashback--transactions');

 if (cashBackTransactionsWrapper !== null) {
    const morePostingsButton = document.querySelector('.cash-back--morepostings');

    morePostingsButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      const cashbackTableRowHidden = cashBackTransactionsWrapper.querySelectorAll('.flex-table.hidden');

      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cashbackTableRowHidden[i].classList.remove('hidden');        
      }
    });
  }
```